# How do I bypass undefined JavaScript errors when doing a web scrape with a HttpWebRequest

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

I am trying to do a HttpWebRequest to scrape a login page's HTML and post data to that web page's username and password controls to 'auto logon' the client essentially. The problem I am running into, is the URI I am using when parsed has JavaScript within and a XML .config file that is not getting downloaded and only available to the actual hosted site it appears.

When I read the response, execution breakes in VS.NET and I get a *"Microsoft JScript Runtime error: 'VerticalMenuConfig is undefined"*

Looking at the script tags where debugging has stopped I see the reference to "scripts/VerticalMenuConfig.xml".

If I hit continue, the page is all messed up when written to the response of my page, and I still unsuccessfully write to any of the input text boxes. I am using an example like the following that writes to the "Search" text box automatically on Amazon; it is exactly what I need to do: http://www.worldofasp.net/tut/WebRequest/Working_with_HttpWebRequest_and_HttpWebResponse_in_ASPNET_114.aspx

Here is the code that breaks:

```
<script language="javascript" src="scripts/VerticalMenu.js"></script> 
<script> 
var vm = new VerticalMenu("tdVertMenu", "scripts/VerticalMenuConfig.xml", ""); 
vm.openSubMenu("clientLogin");
```

It breaks on the line: var vm = new VerticalMenu...

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have logged your webserver in to your client's account and are expecting to serve your client with html from that server.  That probably won't work.  Security, session tokens that the webserver has and not the user, relative urls in the scraped html (like your problem with the xml).

You could serve up an auto-submitting form pointed at the other web server - that form would have to contain the user's credentials in plain text!

```
<form id='f' method='post' action='http://otherwebserver/login'>
<input type='hidden' name='username' value='me' />
<input type='hidden' name='password' value='my password' />
// any other fields that the login page expects
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  document.getElementById('f').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: James - If I wanted to try it out just in theory, what would be the way to actually show the page while logging in and posting the data as you showed? I used your code, and while the data might post, the login page is not displayed. How do I get both requirments to happen? (1st, show page: 'http://otherwebserver/login', 2nd post the data and have it physically auto populate the fields on the screen)?

Comment: You would need a custom hook into the other webserver that would retrieve the login credentials from your app's server if not from  having the user type them in.  If the login page of the other webserver was on the same domain as your main application then you could load the login page in a frame and use javascript to populate the login fields.  However, it probably is on a different domain and most browsers won't allow your javascript to interact with the login page for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a webpage that is already broken, you can't browse webpages that are broken, regardless of using an HttpClient or Chrome.

Comment: No when I browse to the site directly in the browser there is no JScript errors. Is it not possible that the HttpWebRequest does not download all files to the client, and some are only accessable to the hosted site on the server (i.e. a custom .config is not downloaded to the client in ASP.NET site)?

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make any sense. "some are only accesible to the hosted site on the server (.config file)" would only make sense if you were browsing the source code on one end, and the IIS hosted file on the other. The client NEVER sees the .config files, IIS is configured to not serve them. So what would be not downloaded? Now, I will say this, if the page uses javascript to do a lot of stuff, like downloading results via ajax, then this will break, but that's because HttpClient doesn't have a javascript interpreter.

Comment: I think you may have given me the explination I was looking for: "that's because HttpClient doesn't have a javascript interpreter" Check my original post because I added the code that breaks at the end. Does that show what you were explaining?

Comment: @AtConway ~ It does indeed explain what was broken. But do remember, IIS will NEVER serve .config pages _unless_ you explicitly tell it to. And that takes some digging.